# golang otto Load the JS error

Tags: go

Otto loaded js file error: (anonymous): Line 1:59374 Invalid regular expression:re2:Invalid (? =)  (and 1 more errors)

Enclose main code

```
vm := otto.New()
vm.Set("require", require)
val,err := vm.Run(`
    require("raphael.js");
`)
```

Enclose Load method

```
func require(call otto.FunctionCall) otto.Value {
    file := call.Argument(0).String()
    fmt.Printf("requiring: %s\n", file)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = call.Otto.Run(string(data))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    return otto.TrueValue()
}
```

Js file address (I saved locally)

`http://index.baidu.com/static/js/raphael.js`

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occur because otto dont fully support regular expression.

In the doc from otto they said :

```
(?=)  // Lookahead (positive), currently a parsing error
(?!)  // Lookahead (backhead), currently a parsing error
\1    // Backreference (\1, \2, \3, ...), currently a parsing error
```

https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto#regular-expression-incompatibility